# C++/SDL, Everything appears white

Tags: c++, screen, sdl, sdl-2

So here's my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
bool quit = false;

SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

SDL_Window* window = NULL;

window = SDL_CreateWindow("RPG GAME", 100, 100, 600, 400, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
if (window = NULL)
{
    std::cout << "Window couldn't be created" << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;

renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

SDL_Event* mainEvent = new SDL_Event();
SDL_Texture* grass_image = NULL;
grass_image = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "grass.bmp");
SDL_Rect grass_rect;
grass_rect.x = 10;
grass_rect.y = 50;
grass_rect.w = 250;
grass_rect.h = 250;


while (!quit && mainEvent->type != SDL_QUIT)
{
    SDL_PollEvent(mainEvent);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    //Cia darom
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, grass_image, NULL, &grass_rect);


    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

}
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
delete mainEvent;

return 0;

}
```

Whenever I run the application, the window pops up but it's fully white, I've recently set up a dual monitor, and now having some issues while playing GIFs, but I think it doesn't matter. Thank you!

Comment: Huh ? I'm pretty sure that i set SDL_Texture* grass_image = NULL;

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish between '=' and '=='. As in

```
if (window = NULL)   // bad news cause you just nuked window
```

versus

```
if (window == NULL)  // is window null?
```

Comment: To be honest though although this is correct, if the code posted was the actual code he is using the the app wouldn't run at all, it would crash on the call to `SDL_CreateRenderer`

Comment: @Zammalad - It might return a null for the renderer value instead of crashing. Note that the posted code does not check for that condition, so the program continues on with bad results.